# Calling set on a model which contains sub models

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone model containing submodels which are initialized in the "parse" method of the model such as:

```
parse: (response,options) ->
  attrs = super
  if attrs.child
    attrs.child = new Child( attrs.child )
```

Whenever I call "set" on the parent model with a different instance of a model of the same type, a "change" event is always fired even if nothing in the parent or the child model has changed.  See fiddle demonstrating this here: http://jsfiddle.net/inpursuit/ZP7k9/20/

It looks like the code for the set() method in backbone is using the underscore isEqual method to detect whether an attribute has changed:

```
if (!_.isEqual(current[attr], val)) changes.push(attr);
```

In the case where the attribute is a Backbone.Model the isEqual method will always return *false* even if the attributes of the child model are the same.  Shouldn't this call to isEqual pass the attributes of the model if the item is a model?  i.e something like this:

```
currrentAttr = if( current[attr] is Backbone.Model ) then current[attr].attributes else current[attr]
newAttr = if( val is Backbone.Model ) then val.attributes else val
if (!_.isEqual(current[attr], val)) changes.push(attr);
```

Bottom line, i'm trying to prevent a change event from being fired when a Model is set on another Model and all attributes of the two models are equal.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should be able to pass an additional parameter {silent : true} on set to prevent change from being fired?

Comment: @Evan I want changes to be fired, but only for attributes which have actually changed.  The child model is always detected as being "changed" when "set" is called on the parent model even if none of the child model attributes are different.